# How can I set the focus on the first LI with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I set the focus on the first `li` with `JavaScript` or `jQuery`?
I am a beginner.

**Code:**

```js
$('ul li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('a').length > 0) {
    $(this).find('a').css('color', 'red');
    $(this).find('a').focus()
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="dfruits" class="sinline">
  <li><p class="StockBez">ROBO</p></li>
  <li><p class="StockBez">SQ</p></li>
  <li><p class="StockBez">NVDA</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no anchor element in your posted code. BTW, you don't need any loop here, just use `$('ul li a').eq(0).css('color','red').focus();` and it would work if anchor element has an `href` attribute. NOTE: the css part could be handled using CSS rule: `ul li a:focus { color: red;}`  EDIT: now i read you want to set focus on the LI, not anchor. Your posted code is really confusing...

Comment: Focus is for form fields

Comment: Focus the `p`?  Focus the `li`?  Focus the non-existent `a`?  Set the css for the red color on what? Please refine your question to give us clear direction on your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, to set focus on a non-input element you need to set a tabindex.  Secondly you have no `a` anchor elements thus select nothing here in your markup.  Work around set a tabindex on all the `li` you wish to receive focus, here I just set it on the first one.

Here are some code snips to illustrate

```
$('#dfruits').find('li').first().attr( 'tabIndex', -1);// make it able to focus
$('#dfruits').find('li').first().focus();//set focus on li
$('#dfruits').find('li').find('a').first().focus();// set focus to first anchor

//using cached object
var firstAnchor = $('#dfruits').find('li').find('a').first();
firstAnchor.attr('href','#');
firstAnchor.css('color', 'red').focus();


// using each. set href not in markup
$('#dfruits').find('li').find('a').first().each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href','#');
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    $(this).focus()
});
```

Now since you have `p`, we will actually use that...

```js
// using each
$('#dfruits').find('li').find('p').first().each(function() {
    $(this).attr( 'tabIndex', -1);// make it able to focus
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    $(this).focus()
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="dfruits" class="sinline">
  <li><p class="StockBez">ROBO</p></li>
  <li><p class="StockBez">SQ</p></li>
  <li><p class="StockBez">NVDA</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for help!

Comment: I suspect someone down voted this because adding focus this way is not really a great idea/thing to do which is true but the  point here is to answer the question simply based upon the posted question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put `focus` on a `li` element, unless you set its `tabindex`, because it's, by default, not a focusable element. If you set its `tabindex`, then you can use:

```
/* Put focus on the first li element. */
$("#dfruits > li").first().focus();
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
$("#dfruits > li").first().focus();
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dfruits" class="sinline">
  <li tabindex="-1">
    <p class="StockBez">ROBO</p>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="-1">
    <p class="StockBez">SQ</p>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="-1">
    <p class="StockBez">NVDA</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. In the `HTML` code above, I set the `tabindex` of each `li` element to `-1`. That means the `li` elements can only be given focus programmatically via `JavaScript` and not by hitting the `tab` key.
2. If your `HTML` has any actual anchor elements, as the `JavaScript` code you have provided implies, you can use `$("#dfruits a").first().focus();` to set focus to such elements without using `tabindex` provided they have the `href` attribute set.
3. If you are all about speed in your code you had better use `$("#dfruits").find("li")` instead of `$("#dfruits > li")`, because the `Sizzle` engine tries to match selectors from right to left ([@Mark Schultheiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125981/mark-schultheiss)' comment).

Comment: `$("#dfruits").find("li")` would be slightly faster due to the right to left in the sizzle engine

Comment: Indeed. Nice observation @MarkSchultheiss. I'll include your comment in the answer. Thanks for the help 

Comment: Thanks for help! That’s very helpful.